# FULLTEXT Search Multiple Columns in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

So I've been struggling with this for the last couple days.. I have music genres. Separated by primary and secondary columns. Rock / Progressive rock, etc. And i have it so it'll search one column, just fine. But i'd like it to search either column. searching for help on google. I found that a FULLTEXT search in theory should do this. I setup the FULLTEXT index on both the Primary and secondary columns.. But I haven't been able to get it working.

this is my code that works for the single column:

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM musicgenres WHERE secondary LIKE '%%%s%%' LIMIT 20", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));

$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

$json_response = json_encode($arr);

if($_GET["callback"]) {
    $json_response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
}


$final = str_replace(genre_id, id, $json_response);
echo $final;
```

---

(It returns the results in a JSON format)

I've tried to follow this tutorial i've found that gives this as an example:

```
 $term = "Search Term";

    $sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('". $term ."') as score FROM pages WHERE MATCH (title, content) AGAINST('". $term ."') ORDER BY score DESC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
```

---

the question seems to be either in the SELECT query. or when i do combine it. it causes an error with this line:

```
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
```

the most recent Select query i tried was:

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);

$sql = "SELECT *, MATCH(primary, secondary) AGAINST('". $term ."') as score FROM musicgenres WHERE MATCH (primary, secondary) AGAINST('". $term ."') ORDER BY score DESC";
```

I've also tried with: LIKE '%%%s%%' (which would be more useful. as partial matches would be nice)

Comment: What error it return? try the query directly on mysql like in phpmyadmin, try to use `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: Error: Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\Web Pages\PHP\GenreTest.php on line 29
[]

Comment: Line 29: while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {

Comment: try the query directly on mysql like in phpmyadmin try the query directly on mysql like in phpmyadmin, what it returns? Try something like this `SELECT *, MATCH(title, content) AGAINST('". $term ."') FROM pages`

Comment: I did'nt realize i could try that.. lemme check.. just a sec.

Comment: it has this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH(primary, secondary) AGAINST('rock') FROM musicgenres LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: But did notice under it, it formats the query.. and it did as: SELECT *
MATCH (

PRIMARY , secondary
)
AGAINST (
'rock'
)
FROM musicgenres  ... is it possible it thinks PRIMARY (as it capitalized it) is a command, and not a table?

Comment: Okay that was part of the issue. (having the column marked as primary) I got that working on the SQL.. now on the page it's changed to this: Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\Web Pages\PHP\GenreTest.php on line 30 .. which is the putting it into an array part:     $arr[] = $obj;

Comment: Wahoo, I got it working thank you.. being able to test it as a query inside phpmyadmin, really helped a lot.

Comment: Ok. new problem. it has to be a direct match, and won't do partial matches.. though i'm looking for a solution for that now. thank you for all your help.

Comment: Check out Boolean mode in `FULLTEXT` search, right now we are using natural language mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this query

```
SELECT column1, column2, ..., MATCH(primary, secondary) AGAINST('". $term ."') as score 
FROM musicgenres 
WHERE MATCH (primary, secondary) AGAINST('". $term ."') 
ORDER BY score DESC"
```

If it dosent work try to remove match() against() from select clause

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for but if you want to search multiple columns something like this should work:

```
"SELECT * FROM musicgenres WHERE secondary LIKE '%%%s%%' OR primary LIKE '%%%s%%' LIMIT 20"
```

Hope that's close to what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried that several times as well.. it causes Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\Web Pages\PHP\GenreTest.php on line 30 - part of turning it into a JSON Response so my page can use it's data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to add indexes that enclose the columns you want to search:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
ADD FULLTEXT `fulltext_idxAll` (`column1`, `column2`,`column3`);
```

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE MATCH (`column1`, `column2`,`column3`) 
AGAINST ('whateveryouwanttosearch')
```

hope this is useful for you.